# Heat transfer equally distributed?

Tags: thermodynamics

When heat is introduced to a copper bar's end surfaces(right or left surface) of a certain volume $cm^3$, is the heat uniformly distributed? In my calculations of heat transfer, I'm using $$Q = mC_P \Delta T$$

In many examples I observe, it seems that the area of contact to the heat source is the highest in temperate than the rest of the body?

Comment: when you use your equation, you assume the heat is uniformly distributed. And your observation is correct that the heat is flowing into the material under the temperature gradient. Both are correct, except the first is an ideal case with the assumption.

Comment: Is the ideal assumption fair for an approximation in calculations? I mean, I'm using this to calculate experimental outcomes.

Comment: Yes, after you do some testing, you will see this point. This is especially accurate when temperature difference is not large.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the heat will eventually distribute itself uniformly through the material - this follows from the second law of thermodynamics. However, it can take a long time for uniformity to be achieved. The gradual diffusion of heat through a material can be modelled using the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation).

Comment: Modeling it using the heat equation is quite difficult, since heat will eventually distribute uniformly through the material is the equation I stated invalid?

Answer (score 1):

It will try to distribute throughout the material but it takes a while therefore it is hottest for a while where it was introduced. Also depending on the shape of the bar much of the heat could be lost to the other sides before it is distributed. In the end the overall temperature of the material is influenced by all the surfaces.

Comment: I like this, it makes sense to what I see in nature, the area where heat is initially introduced is will glow first(assuming high temperature) then the rest of the body will. Is it safe to say the equation I stated is valid for the temperature increase of the whole volume?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and eventually, the heat will be uniformly distributed to the copper. But since the formula of Q assumes a uniformly distributed temperature outcome, it is effectively used when there is none of fairly little amount of heat loss from the rod (due to air convection, radiation, conduction due to contact with other surfaces, etc.) will occur during the time that the distribution of temperatures are still uneven.

Comment: *none or.        To ensure minimal heat loss, you might want to put it inside a calorimeter (but you also have to account for the increased temp. of the inside calorimeter) or a thermos (not recommended) or similar (if they are large enough) perhaps ice box.. Or wrap it with something that insulates the heat inside (like newspapers/tissues/styrofoams?) ...